# ¿Como guardar el Id de un combobox enlazado a sql en c#?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

**Resulta que quiero guardar unos datos que quiero llenar dentro de Alumnos, y tengo un combobox que me aparecen el nombre de las carreras que tengo guardadas en un SQL. Quiero guardar el IdCarrera, pero no se me guarda. ¿Como hacer que se guarde esa Id cuando selecciono una carrera en el combobox?
P.d: operacionescarreras.cs es una libreria de clase.
P.d: llenaritems es el que llena el combobox con los nombres de las carreras
P.d: En el SQL se guarda todo bien, a excepción del IdCarrera, que como mencioné arriba, quiero guardar el IdCarrera siempre y cuando en el combobox se muestren el nombre de las carreras.**

operacionescarreras.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BaseCarreras
{
    public class operacionescarreras
    {
        SqlConnection cnn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        // Método para insertar
        public Boolean Insertar(int id, String NombreCarrera, int Duracion)
        {

            Boolean Resultado = true;
            try
            {

                //Objeto  para crear la conexión  a la base de datos
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TETUI;Initial Catalog=Alumnos;Integrated Security=True");
                // Abre la conexión a la base de datos.
                conn.Open();
                //El string que contiene la  consulta que se desea realizar en el SQL
                String Query = @"insert INTO Carrera " +
                 "(IdCarrera, NombreCarrera, Duracion) " +
                "VALUES(@Id, @NomC, @D)";
                // el objeto sqlCommand  guarda la consulta y la conexion donde se va  a ejecutar
                SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
                // Se establece el valor de los parametros que se pusieron en el Query
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomC", NombreCarrera);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D", Duracion);
                //instruccion que ejectura la instruccion Query
                comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //cierra la conexión
                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception c) { Resultado = false; }
            return Resultado;
        }
        //Método para consultar
        public DataTable Consultar(Int32 ID)
        {
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            try
            {

                String Query = "";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TETUI;Initial Catalog=Alumnos;Integrated Security=True");

                conn.Open();
                if (ID != 0)
                {
                    Query = "Select * from Carrera where IdCarrera = " + ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    Query = "Select * from Carrera";
                }

                SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
                //Execute Reader devuelve una tabla simiar a la que aparece en SQL Server.
                // E esta instruccion carga la tabla de datos "tabla" con la tabla del SQL server
                tabla.Load(comand.ExecuteReader());
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {

            }

            return tabla;
        }
        //Método  para Elminar
        public Boolean Eliminar(Int32 id)
        {
            Boolean Resultado = true;
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TETUI;Initial Catalog=Alumnos;Integrated Security=True");

                conn.Open();
                String Query = "Delete from Carrera where IdCarrera = @Id";
                SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception c) { Resultado = false; }
            return Resultado;
        }
        //Métodp para Actualizar
        public Boolean Actualizar(int id, String NombreCarrera, int Duracion)
        {

            Boolean Resultado = true;
            try
            {


                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TETUI;Initial Catalog=Alumnos;Integrated Security=True");

                conn.Open();
                String Query = @"Update Carrera SET   NombreCarrera= @NomC, Duracion=@D  where IdCarrera = " + id;

                SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomC", NombreCarrera);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D", Duracion);
                comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception c) { Resultado = false; }
            return Resultado;

        }

       public void llenarItems(ComboBox cb)
        {
            try
            {
                cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TETUI;Initial Catalog=Alumnos;Integrated Security=True");
                cnn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select IdCarrera,(NombreCarrera) as NombreCarrera from Carrera", cnn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    cb.Items.Add(dr["NombreCarrera"].ToString());
                }
                cb.SelectedIndex = 0;

                dr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se lleno el ComboBox: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Alumnos.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using BaseMaterias;
using BaseCarreras;
using BaseAlumnos;

namespace base_de_datos_alumnos
{
    public partial class Alumnos : Form
    {
        public Alumnos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        operacionesalumnos opa = new operacionesalumnos();

        private void buttonCerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void dateTimePickerNacimiento_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = (DateTime.Today.AddTicks(-dateTimePickerNacimiento.Value.Ticks).Year - 1).ToString();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cbMaterias_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Alumnos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'alumnosDataSet.Carrera' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
            operacionesmaterias opmat = new operacionesmaterias();
            opmat.llenarItems(cbMaterias);
            operacionescarreras opcar = new operacionescarreras();
            opcar.llenarItems(cbCarreras);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sex;
            if (rdH.Checked)
            {
                sex = "Hombre";
            }
            else { sex = "Mujer"; }
            if (opa.Insertar(Convert.ToInt32(textBoxNoControl.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cbCarreras.SelectedValue), textBoxNombre.Text, sex,Convert.ToString(dateTimePickerNacimiento.Text)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Datos almacenados con exito");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar guardar los datos");
            }
        }

        private void cbCarreras_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnModficar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione el `SelectedValue` del combobox deberias cambiar la implementacion del `llenarItems()`, si defines las propiedades `ValueMember` y `DisplayMember`

```
public void llenarItems(ComboBox cb)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string connstring = "Data Source=TETUI;Initial Catalog=Alumnos;Integrated Security=True";
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        string query = "Select IdCarrera, NombreCarrera from Carrera";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    cb.ValueMember = "IdCarrera";
    cb.DisplayMember = "NombreCarrera";
    cb.DataSource = dt;

    cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Igualmente no recomendaria que programes de esta forma, no es bueno pasar un control de la `UI` a una clase que accede a datos, la idea es devolver el resultado de la query a la db

```
public DataTable ObtenerTodas()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string connstring = "Data Source=TETUI;Initial Catalog=Alumnos;Integrated Security=True";
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        string query = "Select IdCarrera, NombreCarrera from Carrera";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;

}
```

Luego en el form accedes a los datos y asignas el control

```
private void Alumnos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    operacionescarreras opcar = new operacionescarreras();
    var dt = opcar.ObtenerTodas();

    cbCarreras.ValueMember = "IdCarrera";
    cbCarreras.DisplayMember = "NombreCarrera";
    cbCarreras.DataSource = dt;

    cbCarreras.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```